# Xamarin File not found exception

Tags: xamarin

In AndroidAccountStore file I have following code,

```
using(var s = context.OpenFileInput(fileName))
```

However I am getting following error,

```
Java.IO.FileNotFoundException: /data/data/MyProject.Android/files/Xamarin.Social.Accounts: open failed: ENOENT
```

Also I am unable to find a folder called 'file'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is solved the File Path setting was having two folder of same name, somehow, thus the error.